# How do I connect my appixia app to my prestashop contact page?

Tags: prestashop, appixia

I've added a contact button on the title bar but I can't get my contact form to display. Has anyone done this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the contact button `Module` field should point to a new Activity module like `VerticalContainerActivity` which should contain an `HtmlView` module in its body. This HtmlView displays your contact page - put the address in its `ContentUrl`. Most of these steps are identical to what you'll find in [this tutorial](http://kb.appixia.com/frontend%3atutorials%3acmshtml1).

You can see an example of this in the diamonds sample app. Create a new app from the diamond store starting point and see how the contact button is implemented there.

The second important point to remember is that you shouldn't use regular store URLs in your Appixia app. When the user sees them, they would see your Prestashop theme with all the navigation and this will be very confusing inside a mobile app. Instead, make a mobile friendly version of your contact page which doesn't use your Prestashop theme and only shows the contact info content.

**Using the Prestashop Contact Form in your Appixia app:**

I'm not sure this is a 100% good idea in terms of usability. I don't recommend using a web form for contact in a mobile app.

A mobile phone is a communication device. It is has special integration for making *phone calls* and *sending emails* - I really recommend you use these methods instead. Look at the HTML source of [this example](http://clarity-enhanced.com/modules/appixiacartapi/override/cms/contact.html) to see how simple it is to integrate (it's just a link in your HTML).

In order to encourage your users to contact, you need to ask them for as little info as possible. Your website contact form makes your users type in their email address. If they email you directly through their device (with a mailto: link), their correct email will be filled automatically. Same with making a call, when they tap on the link, the number will be dialed automatically for them.

If you really insist on implementing the Prestashop contact form, this will require some Prestashop php games. You should find the contact form controller in the Prestashop source and create the same form (in php or hardcoded HTML) without your website theme. It will be a little annoying because after we submit the form, we also need to make sure the confirmation message is also displayed without your website theme.

Comment: Okay, but this is not a contact us html, it's a contact us form. How would I implement this?

Comment: see my updated answer. What version of prestashop are you using btw?